# %~dp0 в bat всё равно выдаёт unc-ошибку

Tags: cmd, bat

Привет. Имеется несложный скрипт для скачивания/запуска программки `bginfo` на пользовательских ПК, который стартует с сетевой шары:

```
@echo off
if NOT exist "C:\Bginfo\Bginfo.exe" goto :COPY
if EXIST "C:\Bginfo\Bginfo.exe" goto :RUN
:COPY
mkdir C:\Bginfo
xcopy %~dp0Bginfo.exe C:\Bginfo >nul
xcopy %~dp0settings.bgi C:\Bginfo >nul
C:\Bginfo\bginfo.exe C:\Bginfo\settings.bgi /timer:0 /nolicprompt >nul
:RUN
C:\Bginfo\bginfo.exe C:\Bginfo\settings.bgi /timer:0 /nolicprompt >nul
```

Но несмотря на `%~dp0` вываливается ошибка о `unc`-путях. Как решить эту проблему без вмешательства в реестр?

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт рабочий. Ошибся в имени сетевой шары =/